# Theme.Material.Light override background button color

Tags: android, android-styles

How can I override the default value of the background color for a button in a v21/v22 style.xml?

I made an application that is compatible from Honeycomb to Lollipop and I'd like to make a better style for Lollipop but I can't find how to override the default background color of buttons (for API before 21) to transparent (on API>21 I use `<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">color</item>` and `<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">color</item>`)

Comment: you can use custom background for that using drawable-v21 folder.

Comment: But I don't know the right syntax!

Comment: you can create the selector for the button and apply it as background to buttons

Comment: Sorry but I'm a newbie developer.... can you be more clear?

Comment: i have posted answer check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create drawable like this in v21

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--drawable-v21/btn_fab_default.xml-->
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/fab_color_shadow">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/style_color_accent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

for more information visit this [link](http://frogermcs.github.io/Instagram-with-Material-Design-concept-is-getting-real/)

Comment: Do vote up as well now you have enough reputation  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it worked partially and I try to explain:
now I have a buttons.xml file in the main drawable folder and a buttons.xml file in the drawable-v21 folder, everything works well.

The main layout.xml contains:

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ...
     android:background="@drawable/buttons" />
```

Now my goal is set a sort of "background: none" only for v21 and more. 
Why?
Because if I set a background for v21 buttons I can't use the style effect 
`<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">color</item>` and `<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">color</item>`that I setted in the values-v21\style.xml

If I set up the transparent color for my v21 buttons the BackgroundTint property doesn't have effect on a Lollipop phone.

I don't want to make a layout only for lollipop devices, I'd like to find a better way to manage this problem.